# How to define the order of next/head elements in Nextjs

Tags: next.js, styled-jsx

For CSS in my nextjs project I am using styled-jsx (https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx).

All styled JSX tags (`<style jsx>`) will be appended at the end of the HTML `<head>` element.

However I have another native (non styled-jsx) HTML `<style>` tag that contains several CSS overrides. If I place my `<style>` tag in the nextjs `<Head>` component it will be placed in the HTML `<head>` element but above the other styled-jsx style tags. This will cause that the other styled-jsx `<style jsx>` tags will override my styles defined in my normal `<style>` tag. I want to achieve the other way around.

```
  import Head from 'next/head';
  <Head>
    <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.css }} />
  </Head>
```

I already tried to put my style tag outside of the `<head>` element but this is no option for me right now.

How can I put my native HTML `<style>` tag at the end of the HTML `<head>` element so other styles will be overridden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still looking for an answer:

My styles were overriden by styles like Bootstrap so I was also facing your problem.

In the end I decided to override the order in *next/head* by overriding next.js-Sourcecode.

This is the file you might need to override:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/pages/_document.tsx

You have to move *{head}* down.

After some research I decided to use a npm-module named *patch-package*. https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package
It's straight forward and allows you to create a patch for the nextjs-Sourcecode.